# Sturm-Liouville-Problem with confusing result

Tags: boundary-value-problem, sturm-liouville

I have the following ODE defined on $D_x = [-1,1]$:

$$y''(x)=-k^2y(x).$$

Prom the physical problem, I know that the solution is non-zero and that $y(x)$ is a even function [$y(-x)=y(x)$] vanishing at $x=1$.

The general solution to the previous ODE is given by:

$$y(x)=a\sin(kx)+b\cos(kx).$$

I tried to solve this problem by using two different boundary values.

**Method 1:** $y(1)=0$ and because $y(x)$ is a even function, we can state $y'(0)=0$. Using the general solution we get:

$$0=a\sin(k)+b\cos(k)$$
$$0=ak$$

- Case 1 $a=0$: We obtain $0=b\cos(k)$.

  - Case 1a $b=0$: Leads to trivial zero solution.
  - Case 1b $\cos(k)=0$: Leads to $k=\pi/2+\pi l$, in which $l \in \mathbb{Z}$.
- Case 2 $a\neq 0$: this implies $k=0$ which leads to $b=0$, hence the trivial zero solution.

So only Case 1b gave a meaningful result given by $$y(x)=\sum_{l=-\infty}^{\infty}b_l\cos((\pi/2+\pi l)x)$$

**Method 2**: As $y(x)$ vanishes on the boundaries I can also use $y(1)=y(-1)=0$ as boundary condition. Again, using the general solution it is possible to obtain:

$$0=a\sin(k)+b\cos(k)$$
$$0=-a\sin(k)+b\cos(k).$$

From here there are two possible ways to solve this problem.

**Procedure 1**: Adding both equations:

$$0=2b\cos(k).$$

Case 1: $b=0$, implies $0=a\sin(k)$
Case 1a $a=0$: Leads to trivial zero soltuion.
Case 1b $a\neq 0$: Leads to $k=\pi l$, hence the general solution
$$y(x)=\sum_{l=1}^{\infty}a_l\sin(\pi l x)$$

**Procedure 2**: Subtracting both equations:
$$0=2a\sin(k)$$

Case 2 $a=0$: Implies $0=b\cos(k)$

Case 2a $b=0$: Implies trivial zero solution.

Case 2b $b\neq 0$: Implies $k=\pi/2+\pi l$, in which $l\in \mathbb{Z}$.
So the general solution is given by 
$$y(x)=\sum_{l=-\infty}^{\infty}b_l\cos((\pi/2+\pi l)x)$$

> My Question: How is it possible that two different sets of boundary
>   conditions, descibing the same physical $y(x)$ lead to different
>   results? And how is it possible that for the second method different
>   ways of solving the system lead to different solutions? How can I know
>   which boundary conditions I need to pick, in order to get the "right"
>   solution? I would be glad if someone could point out a mistake that I made or 
>   explain me why this happened.

Comment: Maybe it's because I'm on my smartphone... But what is the difference between the last equation in 1b and 2a?

Comment: One solution of method 2 is the same as for method 1. But the other solution is different.

Comment: The first procedure in method 2 gives you functions which are not even, so they are not solutions to your problem. And you missed case 2, $b \ne 0$, which gives you the same solutions as the other methods.

Comment: Your solution $y(x) = \sum b_l \cos(\cdots)$ is *not* a solution to $y'' = -k^2 y$. Each of these solutions you have added are solutions to that equation for a different value of $k$.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $y(1) = y(-1)$ does not guarantee that the solution is even. There are plenty for function satisfying this without being even. So in **Method 2** your total solution will be a sum of the solutions found in **Procedure 1** and **Procedure 2**. However the solutions from **Procedure 1** does not fulfil the requirement that the solution is even so they have to be discarded (i.e. $a_l = 0$ for all $l$).

In this case it does not matter which method you use as they both yield the correct result in the end (once you keep only the even solutions).